# Doctrine: special characters are not saved into database string field

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, diacritics

im trying to save into a string field (mysql database) with doctrine (in symfony2):

```
$blogpost->setTitle = "Test !§$%&/()=? äöü ÄÖÜ :D";

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($blogpost);
$em->flush();
```

but it saves me: "Test !"
(the rest is missing)

the entity is:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $Title;
```

the mysql database is utf8_general_ci.

(when i add an entity manually with phpmyadmin it works correctly.)

i need to have the german umlauts. hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the encoding for your entity manage connection string:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: %database_driver%
        host: %database_host%
        port: %database_port%
        dbname: %database_name%
        user: %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset: UTF8
```

This way you can have UTF8 characters on all the columns in your database.

Answer (score 2):

In this file  `vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/MySqlPlatform.php`

they have

```
if ( ! isset($options['collate'])) {
  $options['collate'] = 'utf8_unicode_ci';
}
```

Try changing it to  `utf8_general_ci`

Also have a look here

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/faq.html#how-do-i-set-the-charset-and-collation-for-mysql-tables